# RuntimeError (symbol table overflow (symbol _one_time_conditions.))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, symbol-table

My web app now crash that by this error:

> RuntimeError (symbol table overflow (symbol _one_time_conditions...)):
>     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3

The error will appear after about 1 day from start, and resume normal after restart the web application.

Can anyone help to provide solution ?

The version as below:

> ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03 Rails 3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you mistakenly leave class caching disabled in production.

Your rails config/environments/production.rb should have:

`config.cache_classes = true`